# How to query a private table in google-bigquery from a python script WITHOUT authorization token?

Tags: python, html, sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to submit a query into Google's BigQuery and retrieve results - all from a python script. While there's straightforward documentation on doing so, the only option that I've found for querying from private tables/collections is to use an authorization code. However, this python script is utilized via a webpage used by users who know nothing about code - therefore there is no room to get/submit authorization codes, as the user simply uses the webpage and python script by clicking a few buttons. Is there any way to get the authorization code and submit it behind the scenes, or to query a private table without an authorization code altogether (best option)? Thanks so much!

Comment: "Authorize access to something without the password" - probably not a very safe idea, and probably not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a service account:

> Client libraries can use Application Default Credentials to easily
>   authenticate with Google APIs and send requests to those APIs. With
>   Application Default Credentials, you can test your application locally
>   and deploy it without changing the underlying code

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/authentication#bigquery-authentication-python